# Read from JPA repository No property .. found for type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

I warmly welcome,
I'm trying to get one value from my repository. However, I have a problem at the beginning I struggled with a null pointer exeption error. Now I'm getting:

> No property findbyCurrencyDTO found for type CurrencyDTO

!. I am asking for help, I tried in various ways and to no avail.

```
public class Conversion {
    @Autowired

    CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

    public String conversion () {

        System.out.println(currencyRepository.findbyCurrencyDTO("PLN"));


        return "ok";

    }


@Repository
public interface CurrencyRepository extends JpaRepository<CurrencyDTO, Long> {
    CurrencyDTO findbyCurrencyDTO(String id);

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "CurrencyDTO")
public class CurrencyDTO extends CurrencyAPIOutput implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private Double cAD;

private Double hKD;
private Double pLN;
```

///ETC ,,

Test

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(FlightRadarApplication.class, args);
    Conversion conversion = new Conversion();
    conversion.conversion();


}
```

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property findbyCurrencyDTO found for type CurrencyDTO!

[image: Database]

Comment: Your database design makes no sense. Instead of having a single row with dozens of columns for each currency, you should have a row for each currency (pair).

Comment: by this `CurrencyDTO findbyCurrencyDTO(String id);`, what is your purpose and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get one value from db.

Comment: Your current design is really bad. What if you wanted to add another currency? You would have to modify the table! Instead create a table with 2 columns - currency name, and value - this way you will be able to modify, add, update, deleted your currencies in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because `CurrencyDTO` doesn't have a `CurrencyDTO` field. For instance, you can add `findByCAD`. In your case, I suppose you can use `JpaRepository` method `findAllById`.